# Mac OS X running time

Tags: macos, mac

How can I find out for how long OS X has been running after the reboot?
Is it the kernel_task process' CPU Time value in Activity Monitor? If so, what format it is in? X:XX,XX?
How sleep/hibernate affects the time value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open Terminal app and type `uptime`:

```
$ uptime
 12:01pm  up 2 days  3:52,  3 users,  load average: 3.37, 2.63, 2.31
```